# Kubuntus panel option auto-hide, is not always auto-hiding

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, panel

I activated auto-hide panels but they dont always hide, sometimes I have to hover with the mouse on the panel and then remove the mouse and then it hides.
Sometimes that doesnt work and I have to click on a panel and then remove the mouse and then the panel hides.

Im also using two monitors, my second monitor is on the left side and the auto-hide option doesnt work at all on that side, until I move the second monitor and place it in another direction.

So to sum up my question: Why is this happening and how can I make the panels auto-hide work properly?